# Internal+external interfaces with multiple default gateways on Win2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, load-balancing, gateway

I'm trying to set up several web servers for a load balanced cluster and need to have each server connected to the internal network (for load balancing) as well as to an external network (Internet - for administration).

I have two NICs, but since I can't set two default gateways I have the external gateway as default and the internal as a route rule.

This setup only works half way—the internal network is fine, but I can't log in from outside or see the web from the box. If I switch the gateways, remote login/web will work, but the internal won't.

I'm sure someone encountered this before, but I wasn't able to find anything online.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to set up two default gateways? Its the gateway the server sends packets to if he doesnt know the address and has no route. So there can only be one. Or else how decide?

Can you see the web if you only set the external gateway as default gateway on the external NIC? Without additional routes? Why do you need additional routes? Can you paste the output of route print?